# Repair one string relative to another in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Query     "AAAAA-AAACAAA-AAAAAA"

Reference "AA-AATAAAAAAATAAAAAA"

In Python,how do I repair a string (Query) relative to a Reference string where dashes in the query are substituted for the reference character, and dashes in the Reference string result in deletions in the corresponding Query character?

"AAAAA-AAACAAA-AAAAAA" should become

"AAAATAAACAAATAAAAAA"
(where parantheses here "AA()AA(T)AAACAAA(T)AAAAAA" highlight the modified characters)

Below is code that can repair the dashes in the Query relative to the reference which may or may not be helpful(line numbers are specific to the file, not relevant here, I apologize for the non-pythonic code!), but I cannot modify the Query according to dashes in the reference....

```
    if "Query identifier" in line:
        Query = line[24:-12]

        if "-" in Query:
            indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(Query) if x == "-"]
            QueryStringUntilFirstDash = Query[:indices[0]]
            found = 2

    if found ==2 and "Reference identifier" in line:
        Ref = line[24:-12]

        if len(indices) == 1:
            QueryDashToEnd.append(Query[indices[0]+1:])
            print QueryStringUntilFirstDash+Ref[indices[0]]+str(QueryDashToEnd[0])
            del(A[:])

        else:

            while y < len(indices):
                    y+=1

                    if y < len(indices):

                        DashesMiddleofQuery.append(Query[indices[y-1]:indices[y]])

                        DashesMiddleofQuerySubstitution = [B.replace('-', Ref[indices[y-1]]) for B in B]

                        Concat= ''.join(B)

            del(B[:])
            print UID
            print Beg+str(Concat)+Query[indices[-1]+1:]+">1"
            found = 0
            y = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, something like this might work:

```
>>> query = "AAAAA-AAACAAA-AAAAAA"
>>> ref = "AA-AATAAAAAAATAAAAAA"
>>> fixed = ''.join(r if q == '-' else '' if r == '-' else q
...     for q,r in zip(query, ref))
>>> 
>>> fixed
'AAAATAAACAAATAAAAAA'
```

Or if you want to push the logic into a function:

```
>>> def fixer(q,r):
...     if q == '-':
...         return r
...     if r == '-':
...         return ''
...     return q
... 
>>> fixed = ''.join(map(fixer, query, ref))
>>> fixed
'AAAATAAACAAATAAAAAA'
```

I think it's easier to think in terms of pairs of characters, and what to do with those directly, rather than indices.

Comment: Wow, that is slightly better than my code...(haha)

Thanks so much, so simplistic, it is just beautiful!

Comment: What if the location of the dashes mattered, say, if the dashes between the Query and the Ref were less than X spaces away from each other, then do not change?

Comment: @Vince: for that we'd have to involve the indices, which would be a little less elegant.  It'd be quite a different problem.